# Custom swipeable Table View Cell, Close other once new one open

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm following tutorial from raywenderlich ([How To Make A Swipeable Table View Cell With Actions](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views#comments)) site, that shows you how to create custom cell with layers and delegate.

Now I got everything working correctly, buy I would like one of my cells to close if other cell open, how can I achieve this? or Like Messenger app, don't allow users to open another cell option unless they close the current one.

I can't wrap my head around this, I see few other people also ask the same question in comments, but no one reply.

Anyone with Objective-C knowledge, it's okay, I can translate it to swift myself.

The reason I'm using this tutorial, is because the Apple API doesn't allow custom button (using PaintCode) to be used as Action button.

Comment: Do you mean when you swipe one but touch another the original swiped stops being swipes?  Is this what you mean by "close"?

Comment: Basically don't allow user to swipe on other cells unless they select an option or swipe back to default state (which is close) @GuyLowe

Answer (score 1):

I find a very simple solution for anyone else who trying to achieve the same method.

#### Create a Method -  **closeOtherCells:**

Since we store all cells in NSMutableSet we can see which ones are available for closing.

```
func closeOtherCells(close close: Bool){
    if close{

        //Check For Available Cell
        for cells in cellsCurrentEditing {

            //Get Table Cells at indexPath
            var cellToClose: CustomTableViewCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(cells as! NSIndexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

            //Call Reset Method in our Custom Cell.
            cellToClose.resetConstraintContstantsToZero(true, notifyDelegateDidClose: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Now Simply in your `cellDidOpen:` delegate method call `closeOtherCells:` with true parameter.

```
func cellDidOpen(cell: UITableViewCell) {

    //Close Other Cells
    closeOtherCells(close: true)

    //Store Open Cell in NSMutableSet
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!
    self.cellsCurrentEditing.addObject(indexPath) 
}
```

I hope this help others. :)